# MySQL Nested Statement

Tags: php, mysql, nested

```
if ($resultdetails == FALSE) {
    $querynewid = "select * from customer_det order by ID desc limit 1";
    $resultnewid = mysql_query($querynewid);
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($resultnewid)) {
        $uid = $row['id'];
        echo $uid;
    }
}
```

Is this a valid nested statement to make?  It won't echo $uid for some reason?

Comment: First step: Exchange that 'echo' with a 'var_dump'. Also, 'var_dump' $row. Reason:Your query most likely is failing for some reason, or it simply can't find a thing. The code itself looks valid.

Comment: If $resultnewid equals 'NULL' (check with var_dump), that means your query is faulty. In that case, echo mysql_error. This will give you a hint as to what's wrong.

Comment: After ATaylor's comments, you can print query and run in mysql client to see if there is something for you.

Comment: Not logic part: `limit 1` and `while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($resultnewid))`. There is only 1 result..

Comment: I am guessing $resultdetails is never false, can you provide that part?

Comment: It's dumping the entire array, and I see the ID described as a Array(34) { [0]=> string(3) "359".  So I'm not sure how it's losing that, the field is ID in the mysql table.  It's the auto incremented primary key.

Comment: You really need to avoid using the creaky old `mysql_query` interface. Unless you use it perfectly your application will be vulnerable to [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: @tadman You've commented before on a post of mine I believe.  I should just include a footer with all my posts saying that this server is running PHP 4 without the MySQLi module enabled.

Comment: Also you can do `echo $row['id'];` vs `$uid = row['id'];echo $uid;`

Comment: If you're subject to constraints like that, it is very relevant to the question. You might even want to tag problems of that sort `php4` just to be clear. If you can get `mysqli` enabled, though, you probably want to do that. If you need a reason as to why, you might want to test your app with a [SQL vulnerability testing tool](http://sqlmap.org/) and show the report to your decision makers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_row`. The last one returns a numerical indexed-array, so `id` is not a key in that result set. `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns an associative array, so the field name is also the name of the key. By the look of your code, that is what you want.

See the difference [here](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_row) and [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).

Comment: Nice @Oldskool, this pulled the ID perfectly.

Comment: My bad, I totally failed to see that he used fetch_row instead of fetch_assoc.

Answer (score 1):

How I usually handle this in php is below:

```
if ($resultdetails == FALSE) {
    $querynewid = mysqli_query($dbc,"select * from customer_det order by ID desc limit 1";) or die (mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($querynewid)) {
        $uid = $row['id'];
        echo $uid;
    }
}
```

A couple things to know is the $dbc is my database connection and that the mysql_error will let you know if its the query that itself that is broken

Comment: Sorry, the $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultnewid) should be $row = mysqli_fetch_array($querynewid )

Comment: Edited the answer to include that instead.